# GetComponent on other gameobject not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have a script that sits on the player when i enter a trigger it doesn't trigger.
It is supposed to add 1 to a variable score that is in a different script but it just doesn't work.
I tried to test if the Trigger method works and it does so it has to be a problem with the getcomponent or something.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OnTrigger : MonoBehaviour{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject ScoreManagerObject;
    private ScoreManager ScoreManager;

    private void Awake() {
        if (ScoreManagerObject != null){
            ScoreManager ScoreManager = ScoreManagerObject.GetComponent<ScoreManager>();
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        if (ScoreManager != null){
            //When the trigger is enterd adds 1 to the score
            ScoreManager.score = ScoreManager.score + 1;
            Debug.Log("score " + ScoreManager.score );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you assign ScoreManagerObject in inspector (drag the object to the ScoreManagerObject field of your script) and save scene/prefab after that?

Comment: Does your `Debug.Log()` works or is your console clear? I want to ask you that cause if your console is clear it might be that the trigger event isn't called at all

Comment: I did assign the object and the debug.Log doesn't work but if i add another debug.log outside of the if (scoremanager != null) it the debug.log works but the score add thing doesn't work if i put it outside of the if statement as well

Comment: I did still doesn't work

Comment: In your `Awake()` function does the code even enter the if?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Awake()` function you try to get the script of the targeted GameObject, but you store the value in a variable instead of your class property

What you have :

```cs
private void Awake() {
    if (ScoreManagerObject != null){
        ScoreManager ScoreManager = ScoreManagerObject.GetComponent<ScoreManager>();
    }
}
```

What you should do :

```cs
private void Awake() {
    if (ScoreManagerObject != null){
        this.ScoreManager = ScoreManagerObject.GetComponent<ScoreManager>();
    }
}
```

This way, the value of `ScoreManagerObject.GetComponent<ScoreManager>()` will be stored in your class property and your code should now access the `if` in your `OnTriggerEnter()` function